# 'Instance' variables in package

Tags: plsql

I would like to create a dedicated email sending package in PL/SQL. With individual procedures for each email component (from, to, subject, message, etc). The problem is that variables in the package would be overwritten if multiple jobs call the emailer simultaneously.

How would I resolve this issue? Can I receive an 'instance' of a package? Or have instance variables in a package?

Comment: Do you have any code? They will only be overwritten if it was called in the same session by a different procedure, prior to the completion of this one, and you were unlucky, and all of your variables are global. So, it seems unlikely.

Comment: Sorry no code, investigating problem offsite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each job has its own session so even if you change any variable inside job's session the value will not be seen in others sessions. So I don't understand you problem. Moreover your email sender will have procedures like send_email(cc, from, to) so the jobs will invoke the sender with different parameters so what for do you need variables?

Comment: Thank you. I will respond in full with once the solution is done and also have an explanation of the issue.